# Enabling sudo rights to user accounts and disabling root access globally

Tags: linux, centos, sudo

I wanted to enable sudo access to list of users accounts and disable switching to root user (i.e sudo su - or su -). What is the step that I wanted to follow to enable this approach in CentOS7?

**In addition, I wanted to disable reboot / shutdown command to list of users, is this possible?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow the user `alice` to run commands as root using `sudo`, add the following line to the sudoers file:

```
alice ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL
```

To allow all the users in the group `administrators` to run commands as root using `sudo`, add the following line to the sudoers file:

```
%administrators ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Use the command `visudo` to edit the sudoers file. Don't edit the file directly: you may break it and find yourself locked out of the root account. It is strongly recommended to keep a running shell as root in one terminal while you do this, and verify in another terminal that you can still gain access to the root account.

Users who can run commands as root can successfully run `sudo su -`. You could prevent that from working, but it would be completely pointless since you can't prevent variations such as `sudo -i`, `sudo bash --login`, etc. Either you trust people to run commands as root, or you don't.

Users can't access the root account with `su -` unless they know the root password. If you don't want them to be able to become root without sudo, don't given them the root password.

If you want to allow a user to reboot but not to run arbitrary commands as root, you can give them the permission to run `reboot`, or more generally `shutdown`, e.g.

```
charlie ALL = (root) /sbin/reboot
```

Of course, users who can run arbitrary commands as root can reboot if they want. Once again, *everything* includes rebooting, and “everything except rebooting” is not possible since there are infinitely many variations like “wait one second then reboot”, “send an email then reboot”, etc.

Users who are logged in on the console are allowed to reboot by default if there are no users who are logged in remotely. To disable this, modify the [polkit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit) rules. I don't know exactly which file to modify on CentOS.

Comment: So for enabling sudo access to each user, I need to touch this file 'sudoers' manually all the time?

Comment: @GokulnathKumar Yes, if you want to enable access for each user individually. When there are many users, it may be easier to use a group, as I explain in my second paragraph. Then you never need to modify `sudoers` after the first time.

Comment: Is there a difference between `%administrators ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL` and `%administrators ALL= (ALL) ALL`

Comment: Also, if a users with sudo rights can become root and fire any commands. It will be very difficult for us to identify who fired what commands. So there should be some way to restrict this behavior?

Comment: @GokulnathKumar In terms of security, no, but `(ALL:ALL)` is more convenient. `(ALL:ALL)` allows directly running `sudo -u someuser -g somegroup` whereas `(ALL)` requires going through root and then downgrading privileges.

Comment: Once again, if you don't trust a user, don't give them root access. If you want logs that are a bit out of the way, activate auditing. But if someone has root access, they can erase the logs if they want.

Comment: Most systems have a group `sudoers` or `wheel`. If you are a member, then you have full sudo privileges. Therefore no need to add group administrators.